# I would like to perform a BULK copy with this code, please?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle9i

I think this one will do the job of writing all the files to a directory all at once if I can get past the "invalid operation error"

Your help, as always, is greatly appreciated.

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE GetbFile
IS
   l_output    utl_file.file_type;
   vstart      NUMBER := 1;
   bytelen     NUMBER := 32000;
   x           NUMBER;
   my_vr       RAW(32000);
   v_name     VARCHAR2(32760);
BEGIN
   FOR recFiles IN (SELECT dbms_lob.getlength(BLOB_VALUE) as len,
                           FILE_NAME,
                           BLOB_VALUE from Gfile)
   LOOP
      l_output := utl_file.fopen('THE_DIR', 'file_name'||'.dot', 'w', 32760);
      IF recFiles.len < 32760 THEN
         utl_file.put_raw(l_output, recFiles.BLOB_VALUE);
         utl_file.fflush(l_output);
      ELSE -- write in pieces
         vstart := 1;
         WHILE vstart < recFiles.len
         LOOP
            dbms_lob.read(recFiles.BLOB_VALUE, bytelen, vstart, my_vr);
            utl_file.put_raw(l_output, my_vr);
            utl_file.fflush(l_output);
            -- set the start position for the next cut
            vstart := vstart + bytelen;
            -- set the end position if less than 32000 bytes
            x := x - bytelen;
            IF x < 32000 THEN
               bytelen := x;
            END IF;
         END LOOP;
      END IF;
     End Loop;
      dbms_output.put_line('End');
      utl_file.fclose(l_output);
END GetFile;
```

Comment: What do you want to do with your exported blobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Why did you replace the prior version of the code with this version?  If you already have a version of the code that is working to write a single BLOB to the file system, it's very easy to just call that code in a loop.  It's also a better way of designing modular code.
2. When you get an error, please post the error stack.  That will include the Oracle error number, the error message, and the line number of the error.  Tell us what line that corresponds to in your code (particularly if there are formatting differences between what you post here and what code you actually run).
3. You cannot in a single thread copy every LOB to a file at the same time.  A single thread can do one thing at a time so it can copy one file at a time.  You can loop so that you copy each file sequentially.  I'm still not clear whether that is what you want to do or if you really want to spawn 800 threads each of which writes a single LOB to the file system.
4. You need to close the file inside the loop since you open the file in the loop (note that keeping the old code would make it much easier to avoid this sort of error).  And assuming that you want to use the file name from the table, you'd want to use `recFiles.file_name` in your call to `fopen`, not a hard-coded string 'file_name' which would try to write every LOB to the same physical file.

Given that, my guess is that you want something like this (note that it would still be better form to modularize this code but since you're trying to avoid that, I'll assume you have a good reason for that)

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE GetbFile
IS
   l_output    utl_file.file_type;
   vstart      NUMBER := 1;
   bytelen     NUMBER := 32000;
   x           NUMBER;
   my_vr       RAW(32000);
   v_name     VARCHAR2(32760);
BEGIN
   FOR recFiles IN (SELECT dbms_lob.getlength(BLOB_VALUE) as len,
                           FILE_NAME,
                           BLOB_VALUE from Gfile)
   LOOP
      l_output := utl_file.fopen('THE_DIR', recFiles.file_name||'.dot', 'w', 32760);
      IF recFiles.len < 32760 THEN
         utl_file.put_raw(l_output, recFiles.BLOB_VALUE);
         utl_file.fflush(l_output);
      ELSE -- write in pieces
         vstart := 1;
         WHILE vstart < recFiles.len
         LOOP
            dbms_lob.read(recFiles.BLOB_VALUE, bytelen, vstart, my_vr);
            utl_file.put_raw(l_output, my_vr);
            utl_file.fflush(l_output);
            -- set the start position for the next cut
            vstart := vstart + bytelen;
            -- set the end position if less than 32000 bytes
            x := x - bytelen;
            IF x < 32000 THEN
               bytelen := x;
            END IF;
         END LOOP;
      END IF;
      utl_file.fclose(l_output);
     End Loop;
     dbms_output.put_line('End');
END GetFile;
```

Comment: First thanks for your response. I have replace the original code with the one that explains more clearer what I am trying to do. If you look at the code I just posted, each time I run it, I get "Invalid Operation" error. This tells me with my limited knowledge that The way I have the directory name, either I don't have permission to reach it or the directory is not being recognized. ANd yes, that original is writing one file at a time which is a pain. The one I just posted now is supposed to copy entire files at same time. Can you please help with the invalid operation error?

Comment: @ChidiOkeh - Why did you replace the original code?  If the original version was working correctly to export a single file, calling it in a loop should be a snap (as I showed).  If you're getting an error with this version of the code, post the error stack.  There will be an Oracle error number, an error message, and a line number.  Tell us what line that corresponds to.  As I mentioned when your colleague posted this code on the OTN forums, at a minimum, you would need to close the file in the loop.  You're also using the same file name every time you open the file.

Comment: Thank you Justin. Please understand that I am a complete idiot when it comes to Oracle. I would love to do what you suggested. I am just at a loss as to how to put them all together. If you still want me to post the original code for your assistance, I would gladly do so. Again, lots of thanks for your assistance. I will try this now.

Comment: Justin, I am getting an error that 14/49    PLS-00201: identifier 'REC_FILES.FILE_NAME' must be declared

Comment: @ChidiOkeh - That was a typo.  It should have been recFiles since that's what you named your cursor.  I fixed the typo.

Comment: Thank you Justin but now I get this: ORA-29285: file write error

Comment: @ChidiOkeh - OK.  What line is that error being thrown on?  What is on that line?

Comment: Here it shows 3 different line numbers: ORA-29285: file write error ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 18 ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 993 ORA-06512: at "USER.GETBFILE", line 24 ORA-06512: at line 2  More specific info: utl_file.fflush(l_output);line 18

utl_file.put_raw(l_output, my_vr); line 24 

create or replace line 1

Comment: Thank you very much Justin. It worked. I guess the write error meant that buffer may have been full. I shut down everything last night, restarted this morning and the copy worked. Again, thanks a lot.